# How to work with angular js on local system? What all setup I will need?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs, wanted to try out a simple program.

How to execute angular js on local system? What all setup I will need?

Comment: nothing special other than must open page on a localhost server if want to use directive templates or includes that would be imported using ajax

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to download angularjs from https://angularjs.org/ if you want it to work offline whilst developing, otherwise you can use a CDN (Content Delivery Network) and place a link to angular in the script's 'src' attribute value.

CDN link for Angular 2 using https://cdnjs.com/: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.17/angular2.min.js

Place the downloaded angular.js file into your project folder and reference it from your html file.

You're then good to go.

Comment: don't even need to download it if use cdn resource

Answer (score 0):

There is no special requirements to run angular js. You could reference Angualarjs by file angular.min.js or cdn in html. A simple code from [W3CShool](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">
    <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```